# Use pfSense for outgoing mail?

Tags: firewall, email-server, pfsense

How/Can/Should I use my pfSense router as an outgoing mail server?

I have several webservers and devices on my internal network that need to send mail out to the Internet. However, I don't need a traditional internal mail server with mailboxes because we use Google Apps.

I have been using Postfix on an internal Debian box, but would like to simplify things if I can and reduce the number of servers I am maintaing.

Comment: Not the way I'd go. Keeping these functions separate would be a better route in the end.

Answer (score 2):

> How/Can/Should I use my pfSense router as an outgoing mail server?

Short answer: you shouldn't do this. Really.

Let pfSense be your router/firewall. It does very good at that, and it's advisable to separate routing/security functions on your network from application-level functions.

That said, there *is* a "Postfix forwarder" package available for pfSense that may do what you need. I haven't used it (due to the above reasons), so I can't vouch for its functionality or utility.

[image: postfix forwarder details screenshot]

But really, don't do this. Keep running postfix on an internal server. It's trivial to maintain an internal SMTP server for these purposes. Additionally, when it comes time to upgrade pfsense, there's no guarantee that the Postfix Forwarder package will be compatible, which will break your mail delivery.

Comment: +1. Because of maintainability, usage of `pfSense` packages should be kept at a minimum. Maintaining a `postfix` server for this is very basic.